# Why head in the linked list is changing?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, insert

I am trying to insert a node at the end of linked list. I took a reference in the method which is pointing to head. I then moved the head to last of the linked list and then added a new node.

```
public class InsertNode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyNode head = new SinglyNode(5);
        head.next = new SinglyNode(3);
        head.next.next = new SinglyNode(7);

        // insert at the last
        SinglyNode startAfterInsertion = insertSinglyNodeAtLast(head, 6);
        printSinglyLinkedList(startAfterInsertion); // prints 5 3 7 6 which is fine
        printSinglyLinkedList(head); // this prints 5 3 7 6 but prior to the insertopn method call, it was 7 6
    }

    // printing all the elements in the linked list
    private static void printSinglyLinkedList(SinglyNode startAfterInsertion) {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        while (startAfterInsertion != null) {
            System.out.println(startAfterInsertion.data);
            startAfterInsertion = startAfterInsertion.next;
        }
    }

    private static SinglyNode insertSinglyNodeAtLast(SinglyNode head, int data) {
        SinglyNode append = new SinglyNode(data);
        append.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            return append;
        }
        SinglyNode ref = head; // took a reference to the head so that I could be able to move head
        while (head.next != null) { // to move the head till the end of the linked list
            head = head.next;
        }
        head.next = append; // appended the new node at the last
        printSinglyLinkedList(head); // printing head which prints 7 6
        return ref; // ref should be 5 3 7 6
    }
}
```

The following is my output:-

```
7
6

5
3
7
6

5
3
7
6
```

How is the "head" modified inside the #insertSinglyNodeAtLast and in main method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is over `head` instead of `ref`. Change

```
SinglyNode ref = head; //took a reference to the head so that I could be able to move head
while(head.next!=null) { //to move the head till the end of the linked list
    head =head.next;
}
head.next = append; //appended the new node at the last
```

to

```
SinglyNode ref = head; //took a reference to the head so that I could be able to move head
while(ref.next!=null) { //to move the head till the end of the linked list
    ref =ref.next;
}
ref.next = append; //appended the new node at the last
```

and then

```
return ref;
```

should be

```
return head;
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott Frisch. I do have one following question:- Why head is updated if the loop and adding a new node is done on ref?

Comment: @SiddharthShankar Step through the code with a debugger, or trace the execution on paper.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott Frisch I was missing the memory reference concept. I debugged through it and found out that the memory location where head and ref is pointing to are the same and if a node is appended, it will update the last element of both head and ref.